# Printf use in Java

Tags: java, printf

I got a question about `printf` in a program, in the end i wrote：

```
System.out.print(area[i]+" ");
```

It prints:

```
2.000000000000001 12.0 28.274333882308138
```

Then I tried to use `printf` to replace it:

```
System.out.printf("%4.1f",area[i]+" ");
```

However, it has errors when it was executed:

```
f != java.lang.String
```

I know probably it is because `4.1` is wrong configuration for the value of `2.000000000000001`, as there wont be 4 digits wide if I only retrieve 1 digit after the dot, but what does the error message mean?

Answer (score 3):

Due to the concatenation operator `+`; `area[i] + " "` is a `java.lang.String` type. The error on execution is telling you this.

Error messages are your friends. Do learn to appreciate them.

Answer (score 1):

The error may comme from the fact that in your expression :

```
System.out.printf("%4.1f",area[i]+" ");
```

You don't print a float, but a String (yes, area[i]+" " is a String).

Try with :

```
System.out.printf("%4.1f",area[i]);
```

It should go better, doesn't it ?

Comment: The " " is a String. And when you concatenate anything with a String, it becomes a String.